# Persistent USB boot error

Tags: boot, 18.04, live-usb, persistence

I made a (persistent) bootable USB of Ubuntu 18.04 I get the error below.

[image]

```
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell(ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

I put some stuff in the terminal from someone else with a similar error. It didn’t work. Can anybody help me. I have a HP Laptop.
I made the persistant USB with Ubuntu 18.04 on virtual box.

Comment: Try a boot disk creator, for Windows, use Rufus, https://rufus.akeo.ie/ , UNetbootin, https://unetbootin.github.io/ or YUMI, https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ For Linux try mkusb, https://unetbootin.github.io/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb or UNetbootin,

Comment: I used mkusb to make this. After starting this error happens

Comment: Did you check MD5SUM of the iso? I usually get an error like that if persistence is bad, memory full, etc. often the result of trying to do a software update, If this is the case, delete something useless in casper-rw.

Comment: Maybe the file system is not Linux's ext format, try Rufus to do so

Comment: I am trying to make a persistant USB so Rufus will not work. My virtual box shows this in gparted: https://gyazo.com/3db08c2d9e51d9cf7759c611ea15babf @C.S.Cameron

Comment: 1. Please tell us more about the computer: specify **model** of computer, graphics chip/card, wifi chip/card; 2. It is a complication, that you made the persistent live drive (with Ubuntu 19.04) on *VirtualBox*. I don't know if it could cause the problem; 3. Which version of mkusb did you use? 4. Which settings did you use (mkusb - settings menu)? 5. Did you check the iso file with md5sum? 6. What stuff did you put in terminal?

Comment: @sudodus
1) [HP ProBook 430 G4 Notebook PC](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-430-g4-notebook-pc/10477243) 
Device Info:
Windows 10 (64-bit) BIOS: P85 Ver. 01.06  Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.7GHz Memory: 8192MB RAM DirectX Version: DirectX 12 

Display:
Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 Display Memory: 4172 MB

Comment: Internet: 
I am pretty sure this is my wifi card: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 It's Hardware Id's are PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_24FD&SUBSYS_10108086&REV_78
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_24FD&SUBSYS_10108086
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_24FD&CC_028000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_24FD&CC_0280
If you need anything else please contact me

2) I am not sure. It was a functioning Ubuntu 18.04 so it shouldn't have.

3) I used MkUSB 12.3.2-1ubuntu4.

Comment: 4)I couldn't find the MkUSB settings. However I used the command prompt on a tutorial I saw. sudo -H mkusb /path/to/iso/filename.iso p and then e. I let MkUSB choose the rest and used 99% of the USB's storage for persistance. (I used the other 1% for an if found file.)

5) 129292a182136a35e1f89c586dbac2e2  ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: 6) In the terminal for MkUSB I put what was in step 4. For the terminal that I had on bootup, only what was on the screen shot above ^.

Comment: Or just go [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AtG6Wei7bTcigVm1zNVhau6cWLXF)

Comment: 4. `sudo -H mkusb /path/to/iso/filename.iso p` is deprecated, and should be used for mkusb version 9, 10, 11. If you start mkusb from a terminal window, you can use `mkusb` or `dus` to use mkusb versioin 12 alias `mkusb-dus` directly. But I think there is another problem. I know there are problems with some HP computers, when you use GPT (default). Please try with an MSDOS partition table (select it in the settings menu of mkusb-dus).